# Rancher - Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc

Tags: rpc, sandbox, rancher

Does any one know how to resolve this error message?
The same Rancher container's were working just fine until about 2 weeks.

Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = [failed to set up sandbox container "e85e08bf70bfbb8cafe4b61b79f47008b4e829310600e5defb29f0a6600d25e3" network for pod "ykgwagg-845b559fbf-clrp8": networkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "ykgwagg-845b559fbf-clrp8_agg" network: error getting ClusterInformation: connection is unauthorized: Unauthorized, failed to clean up sandbox container "e85e08bf70bfbb8cafe4b61b79f47008b4e829310600e5defb29f0a6600d25e3" network for pod "ykgwagg-845b559fbf-clrp8": networkPlugin cni failed to teardown pod "ykgwagg-845b559fbf-clrp8_agg" network: error getting ClusterInformation: connection is unauthorized: Unauthorized]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DG1LT.png)

Answer (score 0):

When I was encountering the error message in a pod describe like the following:

```bash
error getting ClusterInformation: connection is unauthorized: Unauthorized
```

This error is indicative of token expiration issues within the RKE2 canal network setup, leading to a situation where new pods cannot be created.

To renew the token and restore normal pod creation functionality, I have executed the following command:

```bash
kubectl rollout restart ds/rke2-canal -n kube-system
```

This command will restart the RKE2 canal DaemonSet pods within the kube-system namespace.

After restarting the pods, ensure that the token renewal issue is resolved by creating a new pod or verifying that existing pods can now be created successfully.